# Finding generator of a Schnorr group

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated

A [Schnorr group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_group) is a large prime-order subgroup of $\Bbb Z^*_p$, the multiplicative group of integers modulo $p$.

To generate such a group, we find $p = qr + 1$ such that $p$ and $q$ are prime.

Then, we choose any $h$ in the range $1 < h < p$ such that $h^r \not\equiv 1 \pmod p$.

The value $g=h^r \pmod p$ is a generator of a subgroup $\Bbb Z^*_p$ of order $q$.

Question: Where does $h^r \not\equiv 1 \pmod p$ condition come from? Why does the generator need to fulfill it?

Comment: If $h^r=1$, then it generates a subgroup of order $1$, not the subgroup of order $q$ that is desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is because, by *lil' Fermat*, we have $g^{q}\equiv h^{rq}=h^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p$, so the order of $g$ is a divisor of $q$. As $q$ is prime, its order must be $1$ or $q$. Thus the condition ensures the order of $f$ is indeed $q$, not $1$.